# How to create SparklineStack chart by using HighChart plugin as per the screenshot design in the description

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I wanted to plot chart in my application same as the below screenshot. I am using highchart plugin in my application. Kindly assist me to implement this chart by using highchart.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: What should this chart look like with the data?

Comment: @michal, I want to display the number of successful and failed API requests on the chart.